# I have situation wherein the developers do not have access to the server / machine on which the application is deployed...yet

Tags: build-automation, web-deployment-project

I have situation wherein the developers do not have access to the server / machine on which the application is deployed...yet ...I need them to be able to deploy the new war file based on their new development.

I will not be having acces either, as I will be ooo.

What is the best way to handle such situation, if at all.

Thanks,
CS

Answer (score 1):

- Ask your system admin to create a build server which developers has access to
- Write a build script that checks out the latest code, performs the build and then takes deployment machine's credentials from environment variables (these environment variables *must* be encripted) and deploys on the remote machine.

Now, developers code, check-in and then go to build server and performs the build which takes care of deployment as well.

If you are a Java developer you can look into [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) and [Maven's Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a build management tool would be helpful to allow the developers to package and deploy a WAR to a server.  Our organization did a proof of concept of this using Hudson and Ant.

Hudson checks out the project using a CVS tag or branch name, builds the WAR file, and then deploys it to the server.  Since Hudson is web-based, I can access it remotely.  Since Hudson's server is within our company network, it can check out the project and deploy it, creating a layer of abstraction between the developers and the server.

You could also argue that you and your team need some sort of secure VPN access to the server.  But the build management tools would be more secure and also come with more benefits.

http://javatools.wordpress.com/2007/02/23/hudson-a-continuous-build-system/

Answer (score -1):

I hope you have a duplicate machine for development as I get the feeling you have no testing budget...